# Hide URL Address Bar in IOS7 and Android

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ios7

this code has been working on both IOS and android

```
window.scrollTo(0,1);
```

but after the release of IOS7, is no longer working, so I ended up using this.

```
if((window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) && window.innerHeight != window.outerHeight)
```

it works on IOS 7 but not in android.. 
How can I make those two code work together? or is there any option to hide URL Address bar hide on both Android and IOS?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I'm interested in the iOS7 fix. But it seems you didn't post the complete code of it. Can you show me the full code of your iOS7 fix?

Answer (score 0):

This currently works with IOS7

```
function hideAddressBar() {
    if (!window.location.hash) {
        if (document.height < window.outerHeight)
            document.body.style.height = (window.outerHeight + 50) + 'px';
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);
            document.body.style.height = 'auto';
        }, 50);
    }
}
```